# Flutter: Taking screenshot of widget slow for large widgets

Tags: flutter, performance, screenshot

My app takes a screenshot of a large widget using `RenderRepaintBoundary`. And saves this screenshot locally.

Performance degrades for large widgets, say 2000x2500 logical pixel, especially on older mobiles.

it is imperative to keep the logical pixels, so: `pixelRatio:1.0`.

Is there a way to improve performance by using native code?
Or using a different Flutter approach?

I would like to avoid having a server rendering the target image - keeping this functionality inside the Flutter app is preferred.

The code to take screenshots of widgets looks like this:

```dart
takeScreenShot() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = previewContainer.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio:1.0);
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

Comment: @MdKhairulIslam No, I did not.

Comment: @AliIzadyar No, sorry.